# MS Access filtering for date causes Error 3075

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a text field, called `DateSelector` that is formatted as a *Short Date*, and a subform with a list of entries, one column named `ControlDate` contains values that are formatted as *Short Date* as well.

What I want:
If you change the value of `DateSelector` it is supposed to filter the column `ControlDate` to between now and the value of `DateSelector`, or at least be below that of `DateSelector`.

This is the code I have:

```
Private Sub DateSelector_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

If Me.DateSelector.Value = "" Then
   Me.ListView.Form.filter = ""
   Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = False

Else
    MsgBox (Me.DateSelector.Value)
'This is a Check, if the Value is correct.
    Me.ListView.Form.filter = "ControlDate >=" & Me.DateSelector.Value
    Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = True
End If
Proc_Exit:
   Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
   MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " when creating Filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
   Resume Proc_Exit
End Sub
```

The error thrown is `3075: Syntax Error`. The `MsgBox` shows the correct date, where the error message shows the date missing the last digit (e.g.: 05.12.2018 --> 05.12.201) and I have absolutely no clue why.

I am thankfull for any answers, thank you for reading,

_Ninsa

Comment: Me.ListView.Form.filter = "ControlDate >=" & format(Me.DateSelector.Value,"dd mmm yyyy")  might be worth a try

Comment: I would also check to see if the .filter command needs dates to be wrapped in hash characters (#1/1/18#). VBA needs dates in between hashes. Since you getting invalid operator, this seems to be the most likely cuase imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter will end up as:

```
"ControlDate >= 01.12.2018"
```

which Access cannot read. So, apply a proper format of the string expression of the date value:

```
"ControlDate >= #" & Format(Me!DateSelector.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked perfectly. I didn't know that Access not only needed hashes for formatted dates but also dates to be casted for format. I apprechiate it :)